# HTML implement input box that accepts text and images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a comment box where users can input text/images. Just like what we do using Gmail, open a text box, type or drag images into it. How is this accomplished? What kind of  does it use? How does this mixture of text and images translate and gets wrapped into a XMLHttp request with $.ajax()? Or have I over-simplified the question and the way people do this is a lot more complicated than I know?

It'll be greatly appreciated if someone could show me a piece of example code or point me to existing javascript libraries that handle this. Thanks!

Comment: You won't be able to accomplish this with standard elements. I would think you would use a `div` element as your "input" area and set it up with `contentEditable` so that you can input text into it. Next, I would use the drag and drop API and set it as your drop zone.

Comment: Yeah what I can think of now is to use a <div> and dress it up like an <input>. When the user drags an image into it, use the drag-n-drop libraries you mentioned and generate an <img> in the <div>. But what should I put into the HTTP header to make it contain text and images?

Comment: You don't have to add anything. A div can hold text and images natively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I described in the comments:

```js
// Get reference to div, img and button
var d = document.getElementById("div1");
var i = document.getElementById("drag1");
var btn = document.getElementById("save");

// Wire image drag event handler
i.addEventListener("dragstart", drag);

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

// Wire up the save button
btn.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  // First, turn off contenteditable
  div1.removeAttribute("contenteditable");
  
  // Now, get entire contents of div
  var updatedContents = div1.innerHTML;
  
  // If you want to save the contents, you'd have to persist them somewhere 
  // but, all you have to save is the string: "updatedContents"
  console.log(updatedContents);
});
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

img { width:50px;  }
```

```html
<p>Drag the image into the rectangle and type:</p>

<img id="drag1" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9a/26/84/9a2684c4213171476e13732af3b26537.jpg" draggable="true">

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" contenteditable></div>
<button id='save'>Save</button>
```